# Typeahead clickable suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-typeahead

I want to prevent the cloasing of the dorpdown menu on click of a button inside of the suggestion.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search2').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true
        },
        {
            name: 'products',
            displayKey: 'name',
            source: function (query, process) {
                return $.post("php/Products.php", { action:'sell-search',search_value: query}, function (data) {
                    process(JSON.parse(data));
                });
            },
            templates: {
                empty: [
                    '<div class="empty-message text-danger">',
                    '<h3>Няма намерена стока</h3>',
                    '</div>'
                ].join('\n'),
                suggestion: Handlebars.compile(
                    '<div class="row">' +
                        '<div class="col-xs-8"><div>{{name}}</div><div class="small text-success">{{category}}</div></div>' +
                        '<div class="col-xs-3">{{price_retail}} <span class="x-small">лв/{{measure}}<span></div>'+
                        '<div class="col-xs-1"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning float-right products-info "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></button></div>' +
                    '</div>')
            }
        });
});

$(document).on('click','.products-info', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("Cliicked");
    console.log('Inside link');
    alert('test');
    return false;
});
```

I tryed whith

> e.stopPropagation();

but it does not working and the 'test' message is alerted after the menu is hidden.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Does a plugin create a click handler and you don't want this handler? Have you tried to [remove it](http://api.jquery.com/off/)?

Comment: When the user select suggestion the behavior should be normal, EXCEPT when the user clicks on the button "products-info" of the suggestion, then I want to alert('test') and log the lines at console and not to hide the drop down menu. 
What it heppans now is:
1.hide drop down menu
2.alert
3.console.log
4.console.log

Comment: So then... remove all lick events as suggested above and add a new, your own one? `stopPropagation` might not work, because no event is fired on parent elements.

Comment: `$(document).find("*").off();` turn off all events
`$(document).find( ".products-info" ).off();` not working,
the issue is still open

Comment: What about `$(document).off('click', '.products-info')` or `$('.products-info').off('click')`?

Comment: Nope :/ still not working properly

Comment: I think that your solution is `$('#search2').bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
          ev.stopPropagation();
        });`